# Win 10 does not detect internet via Ethernet

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, internet-connection

I have Win 10 on an Acer Aspire E5-773G notebook in dual-boot with Ubuntu 16.04.

On Windows, I can connect to my FritzBox router via WiFi, but not via Ethernet. When I plug in the cable it detects that there is a network, but it warns there is no internet connection.

Windows' automatic problem diagnose is not able to detect any problems.

The Ethernet interface's IPv4 and IPv6 settings are configured to use DHCP.

This connection works flawlessly on Ubuntu, so it is not a hardware issue.

What can be the problem here and how do I solve it to connect to the internet via LAN again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows drivers can be finicky.

Open Device Manager and expand the `Network Adapters` field. Right click the Ethernet adapter and select `Uninstall`. In the confirmation dialog, select the option to delete the driver before clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>. Once it's uninstalled, right click anywhere in Device Manager and click `Scan for hardware changes`. Let Windows reinstall the driver.